# Import from .xlsx to SPSS only works after saving file again

Tags: c#, excel, spss

I'm building a MVC4 application that programmatically creates an Excel document for me. Just a few moments ago I finally got this to work, using EPPlus (http://www.codeplex.com/EPPlus).

This is my code so far (nothing fancy yet):

```
// Create a new excel file
DirectoryInfo outputDir = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\export.xlsx");
if (newFile.Exists)
{
    newFile.Delete();  // ensures we create a new workbook
    newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\sample1.xlsx");
}
Package = new ExcelPackage(newFile);

// Create a new worksheet and add stuff
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = Package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet 1");
int i = 1;
foreach (Isala.Models.Metingen.Type type in types)
{
    worksheet.Cells[1, i].Value = type.Naam;
    i++;
}

// Save the file
export.Package.Save();
```

So, this works. I get a nice Excel file. One problem. For the requirements of my project I need to be able to import this Excel document into SPSS. This works, but the strange thing is: it only works after opening the file and saving it again.

Am I missing something important in my ExcelPackage? Why can't I import my document before saving it again? I sure can't explain this. I hope you can.

(Any tips for a SPSS export library for c# are welcome too, I couldn't find a good one)

[edit]

By the way: the example that's provided didn't work before saving either. Maybe there's something unsupported in there?

[edit2]

When actually downloading the file from a webhost I still can't open the file before saving it. Could it have something to do with Office's nice feature to prevent editing when a file's from the internet?

Comment: Here's a problem that looks like mine, no good answer though: http://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/14919

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you sure that the file you create is actually closed before trying to read it into SPSS so that SPSS can actually access it?

2) The (free) i/o modules available from the SPSS Community website (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral) can be used from C# with a little wrapping code.

Comment: I don't think the document is actually closed when I try to open it, but I also don't know if you can close it programmatically. And by the way. If I download the file from my mvc application it still gives errors when trying to import.

Comment: We tested our application on an actual webhost, the problem still exists. It can't be the file being open, because I never opened it on my computer.